# Call Apex Function on VisualForce page load

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm trying to add a filter to my VisualForce page, with the following code:

**VisualForce Code:**

```
<apex:page controller="CaseController" sidebar="true">
<apex:form id="frm">

 <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!getcasetype}" >
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!casestatus}"> </apex:selectOptions>
     <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!displaycaselist}"/>
 </apex:selectList>

 <apex:outputLabel id="pnl1" >

     <apex:pageBlock >

         <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caselst}" var="c">

             <apex:column headerValue="Case Number">
                 <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.id}"><apex:outputText value="{!c.CaseNumber}" /></apex:outputLink>
             </apex:column>

             <apex:column value="{!c.Contact.Name}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Days_Open__c}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Type}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Priority}"/>
             <apex:column value="{!c.Day_Created__c}"/>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlock>

</apex:outputLabel>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Code**

```
public class CaseController 
{

public string getcasetype{get;set;}
public list<case> caselst{get;set;}

public CaseController()
{
     caselst =  Database.query(
               'SELECT CaseNumber,Contact.Name,Days_Open__c,Subject,Status,Type, Priority, Day_Created__c FROM Case ' +
               'WHERE status=:getcasetype ');   
}

public void onLoad()
{

}

public list<selectoption>getcasestatus()
{
    list<selectoption>selectopt=new list<selectoption>();
    selectopt.add(new selectoption('Open','Open'));
    selectopt.add(new selectoption('Closed','Closed'));
    return selectopt;
}

public void displaycaselist()
{
    caselst=new list<case>();
    caselst=[SELECT CaseNumber,Contact.Name,Days_Open__c,Subject,Status,Type, Priority, Day_Created__c FROM Case WHERE status=:getcasetype AND Owner.Name != 'Dr Sickguy'];
}

}
```

However when the page loads, the list isn't updated until after I change the filter value in the drop-down. I know this is because of the event="onchange" attribute in the  element, but I can't find a way to make it load on page load. Adding an event="onLoad" doesn't seem to work, and action methods in the page element don't seem to work when I call displayCaseList();

Any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: Have you put a `System.debug()` at your `displaycaselist` method and tried page `action={!displaycaselist}` ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default value for `getcasetype` in the controller for exa: `Open`. Then first time the page load your list is populated.

Second Approach is remove where filte in controller and your list will be populated.Hope it will solve your problem.